# C# hide, background, processinfo

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
PSI.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
PSI.UseShellExecute = true;
Process p = Process.Start(PSI);
```

problem is, when I build it, the command prompt still appears. How can I hide it?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, change the output type under Application in the project properties to Windows Application.

Project Properties > Application > Output Type: "Windows Application"

Also try:

```
PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Comment: your code is helpful. however i have question  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6501605/817564

Comment: Did you set your project type as "Windows Application" instead of "Console Application"? That should hide the window.

Answer (score 0):

After copy pasting your code, there's an exception that you probably aren't noticing. `To redirect the IO streams, the UseShellExecute property must be set to false.`

Also, `PSI.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` is not required. Here is your working code:

```
ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
//PSI.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(PSI);
```

Comment: Update your original post with a description of this `one problem`. :)