# minimize every process called C# Processinfo

Tags: c#

suppose i have this code:

```
        string strCmdText2 = @"/C connect.exe --connect 1.txt";
        ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", strCmdText2);
        PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //PSI.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
        PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process p = Process.Start(PSI);
```

the problem is,, when those statements are executed, the connect.exe opens with its window, how can i hide it? like run in background?

thank you

Comment: What's is `connect.exe`? Is this an external program?

Comment: yep connect.exe is an external program... i want it to be hidden when executed from my GUI

Comment: what connect.exe does is that it just pops up a window and i want to hide it when called. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, especially if your running it via the command line... What don't you make the connect.exe the target of your process? rather than cmd.

Comment: if i make connect.exe the target of my process, its the same,, but there would be a window?? hold on let me try

Comment: @alastair,, my current target now is connect.exe,, but its windows is launched. any idea how to hide it?

Comment: i added this: PSI.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;   but still shows a window

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting standard input. Use a TextWriter to write your `strCmdText2` to the process.

**EDIT**: If the above does not work, try this:

```
    string strCmdText2 = @"--connect 1.txt";
    ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo("connect.exe", strCmdText2);
    PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
    //PSI.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
    PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process p = Process.Start(PSI);
```

Comment: hello,, i tried it, but connect.exe still opens its own window.. i want to hide it so the users will not see the behind the scene actions